# Fabrik slideshow basics

Tags: joomla-3.4, fabrik

I am building a Joomla site using Fabrik to display a list of items. The visitor clicks on a row in the list and it expands to a detail view. So far so good.

Instead of having a simple image in the detail view, I want one item in the detail view to be a slideshow of 3 or more images. I am at pains to find out how to do this. As near as I can determine there is nothing in the Fabrik tutorials or documentation on where to start.

All of the forum posts I have read are made by people who seem to already know how to make a slide show, and are asking more advanced technical questions.

On the other hand, I do not know where to start. I would have assumed that by creating an image element and choosing Slideshow as a display property, I would get a slide show of images in the specified directory. Alas, no. It only shows a still image.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image element is an image element. You can use it to display a certain image. A single image can't be a slideshow, so it really doesn't make sense when you say you created an image element and chose the slideshow display property. I also don't know of that display property in fabrik.

For a slideshow you can use the **File Upload** element.
Then in its display settings set:
  -» **Show media in form** as Slideshow.
  -» I would suggest to enable **AJAX uploads**, so you can upload many images at the same time.
  -» Generally play with the various settings like **cropping**, **thumbnails** etc and see what works best for you.

If it's still not working then:

-» Check your browser's console for any possible Javascripts errors, which can be responsible for a non-functioning slideshow.
  -» It might be an issue with your template like not using certain js libraries. Ask in Fabrik forum for support.

Finally, there is a slideshow visualization plugin available... if in any case it does fit to your needs.

### Update

You could create a **textarea** element, with **WYSIWYG Editor** and **Extended buttons** **enabled** in the **Advanced** Tab. Then you can use a plugin like **[Simple Image Gallery Pro from JoomlaWorks](http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/commercial/simple-image-gallery-pro)**, that will allow you to insert and display images in various ways. This specific plugin adds an XTD Editor button, plus it allows for managing your media folders, images and uploading new photos.

### Update 2

A dirty - quick and simple solution for showing the 1st only of your uploaded images in the list is with css.

```
.image___upload .fabrikRepeatData li {
    display:none;
}

.image___upload .fabrikRepeatData li:first-child {
    display:block;
}
```

Here you are hiding all the list items of the file_upload element and specifically set only the first to be displayed.

Of course you will have to use the right selectors as they appear in your list and according to the naming of your fields.

Here the **`.image___upload`** selector refers to the file_upload element name.
Note that you will have to find the way to include this css code in your fabrik list. There are various ways to achieve this. You can search in Fabrik documentation on how to add your own custom css for the fabrik layouts.
An alternative option would be to add your code in your template's custom css file.

Comment: @Peter, I would suggest to play with the settings a bit. Also check your browser's console for any possible js errors, as this can be not allowing the slideshow to play. I am also going to add an update on my answer for an alternative way to add images/slideshows in fabrik forms.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have successfully used the Visualization plugin. The problem is that there will be many many many slideshows and this would be too cumbersome. I need something more lightweight, eg you upload 5 files in a specified directory and they make a slide show.

Comment: Sorry I had to put two comments because it was too long. I also apologise for an error. The element is a fileupload element, not an image element. I tried the AJAX bit you suggest but I am at a loss as to how I upload multiple files. I think this may be the missing bit. I go into the list view, click View Data, then the edit icon, then click Choose File, but I cannot select multiple files. If I upload them sequentially the most recent one gets saved and the other ones are discarded. I will play around as you suggest and let you know.

Comment: I also manually uploaded multiple files to the directory that is specified in the fileupload config area, but Fabrik does not seem to use this directory. It does not store its own images there and it does not load the images that are placed there. Hmmm...

Comment: @Peter, I have updated my answer. If the slideshow doesn't work, then it can also be something with your template. Ask for some support in fabrik forums.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works now. I'm not sure what I did. I just cleared out a bunch of elements and groups I had been playing with, then went to edit the data from the list view an voila, multple file upload worked! Thanks again!

Comment: @Peter, if you think my answer provides a solution to your question, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have never figured out how to accept an answer LOL... ;-) Also, I would like to have just one image in the list view, but it shows all of them :( As a workaround I created another fileupload with a single image but I don't want it in the form view. Display link to file: no. Show in list: yes. Show in form: No. But is displays a link to the file in the form. How to get rid of this?

Comment: @Peter, To accept an answer, you go to the icons at the left of the answer, and there is a check type icon. As for the other questions in your comment, maybe ask another question, or ask in fabrik forums. Generally Fabrik is powerful and there is a lot of customization you can achieve, after starting to know how things work. Such solutions can't be given here for many reasons. I have a rather easy and quick css solution for you though - I added a second update in my answer.

Comment: Solved. The slideshow works perfectly (except the arrows obscure parts of the photo...) But I am now able to limit the list to a single photo. Here is how: In the element properties, I went List View Settings, then CSS and specified a cell class. Then I created the class in my custom template with your css code from above. Presto! Thanks a million!